# Using Windows Server Backup to schedule a System State backup and I get "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-backup, system-state

When using Windows Server Backup on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise to schedule a System State backup and I get "The system cannot find the path specified". The dedicated drive I'm using is freshly formatted by Windows Server Backup, contains no other data, and is a healthy drive.

I've tried searching forums to see if someone faced the same challenge, but nothing has turned up. Also C:\Windows\Logs\Windows Server Backup\ contains no logs when this error message is generated.

I'm using the GUI to schedule a re-occurring backup of just the System State to be backed up to E:\, which is a dedicated spare drive. Only the System State backups will exist on this drive.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us the command you are using and the details (drive letters/locations) for what you are backing up.  E.g. is your system drive actually C:, etc.